# Adding a GeoJSON layer to WebGL Earth

Tags: leaflet, geojson, globe, webgl

How can I overlay the country shapes from [this Leaflet example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/example.html) onto a WebGL Earth globe?

I've tried replacing `geojson = L.geoJson(euCountries).addTo(map);` with `geojson = WE.geoJson(euCountries).addTo(earth);`.

This produces: `TypeError: WE.geoJson is not a function`

I am adapting [this code](http://examples.webglearth.com/#markers), importing the data and making the change listed above, to produce this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/eu-countries.js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var earth = new WE.map('earth_div');
        WE.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(earth);

        var marker = WE.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(earth);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.<br /><span style='font-size:10px;color:#999'>Tip: Another popup is hidden in Cairo..</span>", {maxWidth: 150, closeButton: true}).openPopup();

        var marker2 = WE.marker([30.058056, 31.228889]).addTo(earth);
        marker2.bindPopup("<b>Cairo</b><br>Yay, you found me!", {maxWidth: 120, closeButton: false});

        var markerCustom = WE.marker([50, -9], '/img/logo-webglearth-white-100.png', 100, 24).addTo(earth);

        geojson = WE.geoJson(euCountries).addTo(earth);

        earth.setView([51.505, 0], 3);
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      html, body{padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: black;}
      #earth_div{top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute !important;}
    </style>
    <title>WebGL Earth API: Markers</title>
  </head>
 
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="earth_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such layer type as `WE.geoJson` in WebGL. If you look at the WebGL docs at https://sites.google.com/site/webglearth/, you'll see that standard GeoJSON layers are not supported yet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying